# Power Android phone with portable battery charger and internal battery removed

Tags: battery, power-on

Is it possible to power an Android phone (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S II) with its internal battery removed, using a portable battery charger?

This question is about phone with internal battery that is removable.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible.

You need to put the battery inside in order to switch your device on. The battery completes the circuit, and without the battery the circuit wouldn't complete.

Comment: not necessarily. You can power a laptop without a battery. Maybe you can do the same with a phone. Maybe not, but you'd need a source for that.

Comment: Well, @samsung I don't think I need a source over here because I own and S-II and as soon as I have seen this question over here I have tired doing that and it doesn't switched on ! Mean if I talk about source then I am the source for the answering this question. And one more thing it's a mobile device not a laptop you don't keep mobile devices like laptop don't you ??